# Detect re-visitors using LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I know we can detect a re-visitor using cookies. But, is there a way to detect using LocalStorage only?

This is what I have started with. I have a LocalStorage object called "ifVisited", whose value will change to "true" only when the user is visiting the 2nd time.

```
<html>
<body>
<!–– Some code ––>
</body>

<script>
localStorage.setItem('ifVisited', 'false');
var cat = localStorage.getItem("ifVisited");


<!-- **How do I detect if the user is re-visiting?** -->

if(visit == 1) 
{message=" Visit #1!";
var cat = localStorage.getItem("ifVisited");
<!-----------------Do Nothing------------------>
}
if(visit == 2) 
{
localStorage.setItem('ifVisited', 'true');
var cat = localStorage.getItem("ifVisited");

message=" 2nd Visit, Push Promo"
<!-----------------Push Promo------------------>

}
if(visit > 2) 
{
message=" Visit #3!";
var cat = localStorage.getItem("ifVisited");
age.setItem('ifVisited', 'false');
<!-----------------Do Nothing------------------>
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: How to detect returning visitors with JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655941/how-to-detect-a-returning-visitor-and-redirect-to-a-specific-url?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @IgnacioAra : The example is using cookie, I was wondering if we can do it using LocalStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**visitor counter example below using localstorage**

```
<html>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
<script>
    function displayCounter() {
        // check if the localStorage object is supported by the browser
        if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
            // if the counter has been defined, increment its value, // otherwise, set it to 0
            ('counter' in localStorage && localStorage['counter'] !== null) ? localStorage['counter']++ : localStorage['counter'] = 0;
            var container = document.getElementById('container');
            if (!container) { return };
            // display the counter on screen
            container.innerHTML = 'Hey, you visited this page ' + localStorage['counter'] + ' times.';
        }
    }
    // call the 'displayCounter()' function when the web page is loaded
    window.onload = function () {
        displayCounter();
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (localStorage) {
  var visits = localStorage.getItem('visits');
  if (visits == null) visits = 1;

  if (visits == 1) console.log("First visit")
  else console.log(visits + ' times visited')

  localStorage.setItem('visits', visits + 1);

}
```